# This webpage has a redirect loop in asp.net web forms when disabling cookies

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting an error in my webpage 
"This webpage has a redirect loop" when tried to run the asp.net web forms solution when disabling cookies.

I'm new to asp.net programming.This problem gets resolved when enable cookies,but i need this to be done when cookies are disabled.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Unless you provide your code that may show how/why the redirect loop is created (in the first place), it would be difficult, if not, a guessing game. First guess, "something" is checking for cookies and "breaks" if none exist.

Comment: I cannot able to find in my code where the redirection actually happens.I'm worried about my webconfig file whether it makes that redirection.can you help me in that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but symptoms were a bit different.  I copied a login page to m_login to make a mobile version of the page.  In the login page, I detected if the browser was using a mobile device.  If so, I redirected to the m_login.aspx page.  Unfortunately, I copied that code over as well, so it went into an endless loop (too many redirects).  This, of course, only happened when I used a mobile device to test it.  When I used my laptop and forced the URL to m_login.aspx, it was fine because it did not sense a mobile device.  Not sure if that helps, but maybe someday it'll help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. User was re-directed to ADMIN page, but because user was a 'member' and in the web.config file for ADMIN folder I had set ' ', the redirect was occurring, and getting stuck in a loop.

To Fix this I checked if the re-direct contains 'Admin', If YES, was user a 'member', if YES, navigate to login screen with appropriate error message.